# jQuery check all checkboxes except where row is hidden

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors, row, hidden

This is working well:

```
$('#mainTable thead th input:checkbox').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('.checkbox').prop('checked', false);  
    }       
});
```

The problem is certain rows are hidden and I only want to check boxes where the rows are not hidden. Please advise.

Comment: Wow thanks guys I was struggling for hours. I also tried the each method but very close to that point I gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:visible` selector.

try this

```
 $('.checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `:visible` selector like

```
$('#mainTable thead th:visible input:checkbox').click(function () {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true)
  } else {
    $('.checkbox').prop('checked', false)
  }       
})
```

Assuming you want to uncheck checkboxes that are hidden, you can do

```
$('.checkbox:hidden').prop('checked', false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the :visible selector for jquery
http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

```
$('.checkbox:visible').prop('checked', true);
```